# Can the iOS8 InvertColors function be called in an apps code?

Tags: ios, colors

iOS now has a setting in General, accessibility, "Invert Colors".  It basically provides a negative image of an app's colors.

I have an app that is mostly dark background elements with light icons and buttons.  It would be great to have a setting inside my app to call that invert colors function as needed for specific users.

Any ideas if that setting is exposed?  Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you have no access to the user's Settings, and this is no exception. Your app can't alter general settings on the user's device; that would be a terrible security hole!

However, nothing stops you from putting up an alert or other dialog suggesting that the user might like to do this.

Alternatively, though, what I would recommend is themes. Basically give the user a preference within the app, so that the user can choose or alter the colors of things. Then, in response to the user's setting, you use the appearance proxy to change all the colors thematically throughout the app. There was a good WWDC video either in 2013 or 2012, I think, on this very idea.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I was expecting that to be the case.  However, I'm a little surprised that this one is not exposed since it's having to do with the visual appearance, and the Screen Brightness is a setting that's exposed to apps.  But, it is what it is. And thanks for the pointers.

Comment: It's interesting about screen brightness, isn't it? Perhaps Apple sees that as parallel to sound volume, which is also exposed; they are both simple and are readily readjusted using the control center. But even screen brightness was not exposed to any API until developers complained because iBooks was able to adjust this setting through a _private_ API and rival apps could not.